# JSP - change in date format

Tags: jsp, simpledateformat

I am new to jsp. Iam trying to change an existing date format displayed.

I have included the current code, where we are displaying a time that is 7hrs lesser that GMT hrs. and the format displayed is MM/DD/YYYY - HH:MM .

I need to change this to only display the date and remove the existing hour and minute details. 
I tried changing in the formatter, but did not help. Please suggest.

Current code:

```
int hrs=-7;
Date date = new Date();
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy- hh:mm a");
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(date);
calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, hrs);
formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
String dateToday = formatter.format(calendar.getTime());
```

Please let me know if any details are required.

Comment: Your last line of code uses the same formatter. You should create a second formatter with the desired format.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this line at the last.

```
DateFormat formatter1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
formatter1.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
String dateTodayWithoutTime = formatter1.format(calendar.getTime());
```